# No "to address" in a newlfm letter

Tags: newlfm

The `newlfm` class has an option called `nofromaddress` which deals correctly with the spacing at the top of a letter in the case where there is no sender address. There is no corresponding `notoaddress` option, so if the recipient address is missing the letter has a gap where the "to" address would normally go.

I have posted an example here (code and result):

https://www.writelatex.com/read/bvdzxjdgqhqb

the vertical gap is between the "from" address and the date, the recipient address would normally be rendered on the left of the document, in line with the text `To whom it may concern`.

Is there an elegant way to deal with this?

Only the code you find here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}

\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=50pt}

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\namefrom{Sherlock Holmes}

\addrfrom{%
    221B Baker Street\\
    London, UK
}

%\addrto{%
%    Basil of Baker Street\\
%    221$\sfrac{1}{2}$ Baker Street\\
%    London, UK
%}

\dateset{January 6, 1914}

\greetto{To whom it may concern,}

\closeline{Sincerely,}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\blindtext
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us this gap in form of a compilable but minimal document! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have added an example to the original question.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but writeLaTeX is very reliable and it also has the resulting PDF, which is helpful :)

Comment: I know it sounds strange. The letter needs a from-address and other address-like typesetting, so an `article` class will not help. There are several use cases for a missing recipient, for example, you might want to write a reference for an employee or student and they may need a generic reference to give to several companies. You might want to right a letter of recommendation for someone to get a visa to visit you. I'm sure there are others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line to the preamble worked:

```
\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=-20pt}
```